# Automate packages install from list in portable miktex installation

Tags: packages, miktex, installing, portable

I am trying to update an automated script for the creation of a **portable** miktex installation with specific packages. I can't get it to install the packages.

I have a file packes.txt that contains all the packages that I need (1 package per line) and the current installation process:

1. Download miktex installer and rename it to miktex-portable.exe (as per instructions here: https://miktex.org/howto/portable-edition)
2. Install the portable version to the location I want it (for simplicity I call the folder mikport here):

   `miktex-portable.exe --portable=mikport --package-set=basic --unattended`
3. Install the list of packages (this step does not seem to do what I want)

   `mikport\miktex.exe packages install --package-id-file packages.txt`

   as per https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-packages.html
4. Run `mikport\miktex.exe packages update`
5. Run a test build with pdflatex

The test fails because of missing packages that are supposed to have been installed in step 3. I may have misunderstood the command, I assumed it to be a replacement for the deprecated `mpm require=@packages.txt`. Is there a way to automate this (e.g. *without* using the miktex console)?

Comment: For now I just loop over the lines in the file and install per package. This works, but it seems much slower this way.